# What is the best way to find the biggest subset of numbers separated at least by N?

Tags: r, max, subset, sequence

I am interessed in obtaining the group of maximum size whose elements are all spaced *at least* N units (N possibly decimal) between them, I would like to have something with the following input/output

```
1 2 3 4 5, spaced by 2
1 3 5 | 2 4

35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75, spaced by 10
35 45 55 65 75 | 40 50 60 70

37.5 39.5 40.5 57.7 62 76.3, spaced by 3.5
37.5 57.7 62 76.3 | 39.5 57.7 62 76.3
```

What I have tried is to use the following:

```
split(vector,vector%%spacing)
```

And it seemed to work, but I think that the modulus of a double is responsible of a pretty weird behaviour, where the same values introduced to a function give a different result wether if they come from the 34th line of a data.frame, or if they are passed directly to the function... I prepared this snippet so anyone could try to replicate the behaviour:

```
calculate_solution <- function(parA, parB, parC, parD) {
  varA <- parA/2
  varB <- seq(from=varA+parB,to=parA-parB,by=parB)

  varC <- 1 / parC

  varD <- split(varB,varB%%varC)
  
  print(varD)
}

df_1 <- list(
  a=seq(from=75,to=85,by=5),
  b=seq(from=1,to=2.5,by=0.5),
  c=seq(from=0.05,to=0.4,by=0.05),
  d=seq(from=2,to=2,by=1)) %>%
  expand.grid()

print(c(df_1[34,]$a,df_1[34,]$b,df_1[34,]$c,df_1[34,]$d))

#[1] 75.00  2.50  0.15  2.00

calculate_solution(df_1[34,]$a,df_1[34,]$b,df_1[34,]$c,df_1[34,]$d)

#$`3.5527136788005e-15`
#[1] 40
#
#$`5.32907051820075e-15`
#[1] 60
#
#$`0.833333333333337`
#[1] 47.5
#
#$`0.833333333333339`
#[1] 67.5
#
#$`1.66666666666667`
#[1] 55
#
#$`2.5`
#[1] 42.5
#
#$`2.50000000000001`
#[1] 62.5
#
#$`3.33333333333334`
#[1] 50 70
#
#$`4.16666666666667`
#[1] 57.5
#
#$`5`
#[1] 45
#
#$`5.00000000000001`
#[1] 65
#
#$`5.83333333333334`
#[1] 52.5 72.5
#

df_2 <- data.frame(a=75.0,b=2.5,c=0.15,d=2.0)

calculate_solution(df_2[1,]$a,df_2[1,]$b,df_2[1,]$c,df_2[1,]$d)

#$`0.83333333333333`
#[1] 67.5
#
#$`0.833333333333331`
#[1] 47.5
#
#$`1.66666666666666`
#[1] 55
#
#$`2.5`
#[1] 42.5 62.5
#
#$`3.33333333333333`
#[1] 50 70
#
#$`4.16666666666666`
#[1] 57.5
#
#$`5`
#[1] 45 65
#
#$`5.83333333333333`
#[1] 52.5 72.5
#
#$`6.66666666666666`
#[1] 60
#
#$`6.66666666666667`
#[1] 40
```

Instead of trying to find the reason behind this behaviour, I thought that maybe I can find another way of achieving what I want, or at least maybe discover the right terminology to refer to what I am trying to do.

Comment: It is assumed that the vector will always contain all intermediate multiples of the interval? That is, with `c(35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 65)`, the missing `55` presents a gap.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to have all intermediate multiples. I think it should be independent of the type of sequence.

Comment: In your `37.5`/`3.5` example, how is `57.5` part of the first vector? The closest multiples of 3.5 from 37.5 are 55.0 and 5.85. What is the tolerance you're expecting?

Comment: `57.7` is part of the first vector because the absolute difference with the previous value `57.7 - 37.5 = 20.2` and the absolute difference with the following value `62 - 57.7 = 4.3`, both satisfy the minimal spacing requirement `> 3.5`. Sorry for the confusion, as I had to change the question to fit more specifically my problem

Comment: I see that you are hoping to return a list of candidate vectors. Why is it always 2? Your second and third examples both contain more vectors (of length > 1) where there is a span of at least 5 and 10. Why are you doing this? What problem suggests that this is a necessary thing to do?

Comment: I only intended to ignore the results that are a subset of another result, because I want the biggest set of them all.

I really like your second question. Maybe I am wrong in the way I am approaching it. I am working with frequencies here. I want to know, given a predefined set of frequencies, which is the biggest set than can you form with the biggest frequential span between them? If the biggest set would need a span of 20 Hz, for example, I would only need to calculate an FFT of 1/20*Fs samples, to have the sufficient resolution to differentiate it, or that's what I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function starts by finding the first vector where each element is at least `diff` away from the previous element. It then repeats this process starting with the *second* and subsequent elements, stopping when either a subset will be formed (the `n`th element is found in one of the previous solutions) or there are no candidate sub-vectors left.

```r
func <- function(y, diff = 1, only_longest = TRUE) {
  fun0 <- function(x, diff) {
    if (length(x) < 2) return(x)
    lenx <- length(x)
    x <- sort(x) # just in case
    i <- 1
    leni <- 1L
    while ( (x[lenx] - i[leni]) >= diff ) {
      i1 <- which( x[-seq_len(i[leni])] - x[i[leni]] >= diff )
      if (length(i1)) i <- c(i, i[leni] + i1[1]) else break
      leni <- length(i)
    }
    x[i]
  }
  leny <- length(y)
  i <- 1L
  out <- list()
  while (!y[i] %in% unlist(out) && length(cand <- fun0(y[seq(i, leny)], diff)) > 0) {
    out[[i]] <- cand
    i <- i + 1L
  }
  lens <- lengths(out)
  if (only_longest) out <- out[lens == max(lens)]
  out
}
```

Demonstration:

```r
func(1:5, 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5
func(seq(35,75,5), 10)
# [[1]]
# [1] 35 45 55 65 75
func(c(37.5, 39.5, 40.5, 57.7, 62, 76.3), 3.5)
# [[1]]
# [1] 37.5 57.7 62.0 76.3
# [[2]]
# [1] 39.5 57.7 62.0 76.3
# [[3]]
# [1] 40.5 57.7 62.0 76.3
```

The `only_longest=` argument was a thought at one point. The presumption is that if any of the vectors are shorter than the longest, then you might or might not be interested in knowing it. Just a thought, easily removed.

```r
func(1:5, 2, only_longest = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 4

func(seq(35,75,5), 10, only_longest = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 35 45 55 65 75
# [[2]]
# [1] 40 50 60 70
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `%%` in `sapply` and equal it to equispace/2 and zero to subset.

```
f <- \(x, s) {stopifnot(s > 1); lapply(c((s/2), 0), \(z) x[x %% s == z])}


f(x1, 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 4

f(x2, 10)
# [[1]]
# [1] 35 45 55 65 75
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 40 50 60 70
```

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work for decimal separators. I edited the question because initially I wasn't asking for that. Now it doesn't even need to equispaced, but spaced by at least N... Sorry about the confusion